# No option to choose X11 on logging into Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: xorg, 21.10

I recently bought a Dell Precision 7550 notebook. It came with Ubuntu 18.04 installed, but I wiped it and installed 21.10. On log in, I don't have the gear menu to switch between X11 and Wayland and Ubuntu defaults to Wayland on log in. As far as I tell, it runs Wayland until I open something (like Steam) that wants to use my NVIDIA card over my integrated card and then it switches to X11 for as long as it is using the NVIDIA card.

I would like to stick to just using X11 the whole time for now, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the option to choose X11 on log in to appear. Does anyone have any ideas as to why the gear icon might be missing?

Relevant Specs:

- Processor: Intel i7-10850H
- GPU: NVIDIA Quadro T2000 (NVIDIA driver
  470.86)
- Desktop Manager: Gnome 40.4.0
- Display Manager: gdm3

Comment: Put the cursor on the password section, It may show the option...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look on to the right bottom you will see a small icon, that can be clicked:

[image]

Select "Ubuntu on Xorg" and X11 is actived.

If you can't see the icon, go to your desktop, open a terminal:

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
Look for the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

and remove the leading # sign.

Comment: Thanks, that let me boot into X11, at least, which essentially fixes my problem. I am still curious as to why I don't have the gear icon at all though. Is there any way to make it appear so that I can choose between X11 and Wayland on boot like in your screenshot?

Comment: It seems that the gdm3 shows a larger screen than your resolution. At least lightDM (which I know better) has an option for screen resolution using `xrandr`, check if gdm3 has that too

Comment: I found first power up time I enter wayland, after logout, every time I enter X11......