# Zoom with Wayland - Fails on starting a session

Tags: xorg, crash, wayland, client, zoom-meeting

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 and have been having difficulties getting a Zoom session going. It was crashing each time I started a session, I found it necessary to restart Zoom usually 3, 4 or 5 times before it got going, once started it would stay working.

Ubuntu 21.10 uses a Snap install of the Zoom client

```
$ snap list zoom-client
Name         Version     Rev  Tracking       Publisher  Notes
zoom-client  5.9.1.1380  167  latest/stable  ogra       -
```

In the log file:
~/snap/zoom-client/current/.zoom/logs/zoom_stdout_stderr.log

I found entries that pointed to Zoom not being happy running with Wayland

```
qt.scenegraph.general: texture atlas dimensions: 512x1024
qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.67 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: texture atlas dimensions: 512x512
qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()
file:///snap/zoom-client/167/zoom/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:102:33: QML Settings: Failed to initialize QSettings instance. Status code is: 1
file:///snap/zoom-client/167/zoom/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:102:33: QML Settings: The following application identifiers have not been set: QVector("organizationName", "organizationDomain")
qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()
This plugin does not support setting window opacity
```

Prior to version 21.10 Ubuntu's login screen had a button bottom right that gave you the option to select XOrg or Wayland, that has gone now so I needed a different way to select XOrg in preference to Wayland. I followed the instruction at:

```
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380829/no-option-to-choose-x11-on-logging-into-ubuntu-21-10][1]
```

This worked and the Zoom client now starts OK

Does anybody know how where to put this information and thus prompt a fix to make the zoom-client work with Wayland ?

Comment: Try the .deb version or the flatpak version before deciding it is an issue with Zoom itself.

Comment: Hello Vanadium, I read your comment and decided you have a good point. I removed the snap version and went to install the .deb version, this was when I discovered 21.10's default repositories don't appear to include a copy of zoom-client. I could go adding an extra repository but a little searching took me to the Zoom Community forum where I discovered Fedora users also have difficulties running the Zoom client with Wayland. It looks like the developers at Zoom have a long way to go before their client works correctly with Wayland.

Comment: Thank you for this. It could have been an issue with the snap package, but this shows the issue indeed is with the app itself.

Comment: Fedora users were describing quite a different fault to the one I saw with Snap however the detail included made me think the problems won't get fixed overnight.