# gnome-shell-extension-manager will no longer run... should I uninstall and reinstall it?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

I had it running

gnome-shell-extension-manager

but no longer.

neither from the apps launcher

nor from the command line

1. gnome-shell-extension-manager

nor from Ubuntu Software, Installed, Extension Manager, that comes up with 'loading application details' and hangs there.

the most likely solution is to uninstall and reinstall it.
might that lose some of the extensions (I doubt it).

I am using wayland. (I could try xorg instead perhaps)

22.04.1

Comment: the extensions themselves that I already had set up are still working, by the way.

Comment: Wayland as  said "I am using wayland. (I could try xorg instead perhaps)"

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a Wayland issue.

You have two options:

1. Use XOrg instead, or...
2. Launch the extension manager using:

   ```
   GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/bin/extension-manager
   ```

   Note: The same issue occurs with the Gnome Extensions App. If you are using that one, you can launch it using:

   ```
   GDK_BACKEND=x11 /usr/bin/gnome-extensions-app
   ```

Please see [this bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4881) for more information.

UPDATE:

Here is another approach that used to work (although it does not work for me currently):

```
__EGL_VENDOR_LIBRARY_FILENAMES=/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/50_mesa.json /usr/bin/extension-manager
```

Ultimately, this may be an issue that needs to be fixed individually by each affected extension, for GNOME Shell 42+. For example, the developer of the [GS Connect](https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki) extension just made a fix on October 17, 2022:

- https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/issues/1213
- https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/pull/1486

I suggest opening a bug report with the impacted extensions; you may want to include the above two links, so the developers can see how to fix the problem.

Comment: ooh that one worked, thanks. I'll put an alias in for it.

Comment: You can probably just edit the launcher in `/usr/share/applications`. Also, please remember to accept this answer by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: whilst the application came up, I could do nothing with it. even though , as expected, as the extensions are still working, the global enable button was toggled on, as soon as I clicked on settings for any extension, it greyed out. ie I could change nothing with it. I could browse and install extensions, and installed an extension list extension, which showed in top bar, but it too 'piked out' when I click on any setting.

Comment: This is a shame. It had worked for me previously. I'll keep an eye out for a solution; if I find one, I'll let you know.

Comment: tried to go xorg doing wayland=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf..got a no boot ... clonezilla'd back to last week's.  I'll let it rest for now, I have my extensions that I want for now. and there are manual ways to install/remove.

Comment: update 2022 see my comment in above answer. much the same as this one. I had forgotten this way... I need to put it on a fridge magnet or tattoo it to the back of my hand. I had just before this installed  sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell   ;   sudo apt install flatpak gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software    ;    sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell   . whether that had something to do with it I know not.

Comment: further update, this is on a new install and a new laptop of a different brand. still ryzen though.

Answer (score 1):

Extension Manager (aka `gnome-shell-extension-manager`) is a [**third-party tool**](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager) to install and manage Gnome Shell Extensions. **Uninstall it won't affect any extension already installed and run in your system.**

In your case, you can however try re-installing it via command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

BTW, there's also an official GNOME Extensions app (aka `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`) with ability to manage (turn on/off, configure, remove) extensions. It has to be installed in Ubuntu 22.04 to allow your extensions being updated.

Comment: on first try    

sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs


 "The following packages have unmet dependencies: gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: gnome-shell (= 42.0-2ubuntu1) but 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed                                Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 42.0-2ubuntu1) but 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed                                Recommends: chrome-gnome-shell"
and unmet dependencies also came up installed in Ubuntu Software..

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-manager did not work either.    ps -Al | grep extension
  only comes up with one process, ibus-extension, I dont think that is it. I will work on the 'proper' one and the dependency issues ASAP. I am uptodate on updates/upgrade

Comment: Try running `/usr/bin/extension-manager` command from terminal to launch it. If command not found, install via: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager=0.3.0-0ubuntu2.1` and print the error if any. If command run but failed, also print error so we can help

Comment: /usr/bin/extension-manager 
Gdk-Message: 06:44:40.959: Error flushing display: Protocol error ....  and    ......sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager=0.3.0-0ubuntu2.1
   Package gnome-shell-extension-manager is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '0.3.0-0ubuntu2.1' for 'gnome-shell-extension-manager' was not found

Comment: The error launching extension-manager could be wayland compatibility issue with your graphics card. Did you try launching it from Xorg session. The package is missing issue is vary weird, make sure main & universe repositories enabled via `Software & Updates` utility, or you may try to select downloading from another server, also refresh package cache via `sudo apt update`.

Comment: no longer having the X11 option on logout screen I will need to edit the etc/gdm3/custom.conf to set Wayland false... later     https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380829/no-option-to-choose-x11-on-logging-into-ubuntu-21-10
special thanks for your assistance.
note too I am (apparently erroneously ) using NVIDIA proprietary drivers for an amdpgu setup (which still has a dedicated gpu though). I can try not doing that too. the dgpu is not even being used at present (options on dock to launch that way, right clicking)

Comment: also now I have options to default use of the dedicated card with nvidia-settings.

Comment: update, now on 22.04 and wayland... as I had lost the extentions again. /usr/bin/extension-manager   did the trick, then I got the toggle to show extensions... which is still missing in 'tweaks' app.