# Unable To Install A NVIDIA Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm new to Linux Ubuntu and wanted to change my driver from the stock Nouveau driver to the recommended: **NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage from nvidia-driver-525-open (proprietary, tested)**

I have a GeForce RTX 3070 Ti running on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 'Jammy Jellyfish'.

It comes up with an non-interactive black screen:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 229203/61022208 files, 7625678/244059136 blocks.
```

I've also tried to disable secure boot via MOK and BIOS as it requested but still nothing.

I already tried to delete the drivers through the root in GRUB and reinstall them again, but that doesn't affect anything.

Is there anyway for me to download the driver?

Comment: What actual error messages or other difficulties have you encountered? You're basically just saying it didn't work, without any information that is useful to those who might wish to help.

Comment: Sorry, it says: /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 229203/61022208 files, 7625678/244059136 blocks. It gets stuck on an uninteractive black screen. I tried to also disable secure boot via MOK and BIOS as it requested but still nothing.

Comment: It's best if you add more information in your question, I have done it this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Hardware Installer from Gnome/Ubuntu, it should work. But wayland will not work with these drivers. So log out,select "Ubuntu on Xorg" as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1380838/906933) and log in again.

Comment: When I tried it, the screen goes black and I have to restart.